# How determine the y coordinate of center of mass from timeseries

Tags: python, scipy

Consider the following pandas dataframe, with shape `NxT`, where `N = 10` is the number of samples and `T = 6` are the timesteps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10, 6)))
```

I need to determine the `x` and `y` coordinates of the center of mass (centroid) for each of those `N` samples.

For the `x` coordinate, I have done this:

```
time_axis = np.arange(data.shape[1])
centroid_x = np.sum(data.values * time_axis, axis=1) / np.sum(data.values, axis=1)
```

Which gives the same result as `center_of_mass` from scipy, for example for the first sample `N=0`:

```
ndimage.center_of_mass(data.loc[0, :].values)
```

But I am not sure how can I determine the `centroid_y` for each sample. It is just the mean values, like this?

```
centroid_y = data.values.mean(axis=1)
```

From [center_of_mass](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass.html) page, it should return a tuple, the coordinates of centers-of-mass. Why i am getting only the `x` coordinate value?

**EDIT:** One sample (row) of my dataset is similar to this plot. I need to find the `x` and `y` coordinates for each sample.

[image]

Comment: Are the samples moving? Is the datum in each cell the measurement of displacement in one axis - if so, which one? I hope you're okay with getting a center of mass at each time step and not overall, because if the latter, you have missing definitions.

Comment: @Reinderien what do you mean by moving samples? The data in each cell varies along the x-axis (i have half-hourly measurments, for exampe, first cell is a measurement between `00:00-00:29`, in the second cell is the same measurement between `00:30-00:59` and so on).

Comment: If it's the x axis only, how do you expect to be able to reconstruct or estimate the y axis?

Comment: @Reinderien check edit. I need to find those coordinates. The circle is the center of mass of the timeseries signal.

Comment: So x and time are the same thing?

Comment: @Reinderien Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Following professor Strang class on centroids ([link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/06%3A_Applications_of_Integration/6.06%3A_Moments_and_Centers_of_Mass#:%7E:text=We%20find%20the%20coordinates%20of,y%3DMx%2Fm.)), i have calculated both coordinates like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10, 6)))
time_axis = np.arange(data.loc[: , 0:5].shape[1])
mass = np.sum(data.loc[: , 0:5].values, axis=1)
centroid_x = np.sum(data.loc[: , 0:5].values * time_axis, axis=1) / mass
centroid_y = np.sum(data.loc[:, 0:5].values * data.loc[:, 0:5].values, axis=1) / mass
```

Since the "mass" of each point in my timeseries is equal `y`, i have done the element-wise multiplication to find the centroid coordinate along that axis.

Still not sure how to get both coordinates using `scipy` package.

Comment: It makes no sense to interpret your data as a series of mass against time. If you want to calculate the centre of mass, it would need to be interpreted as a spatial distribution of y and x with each point having constant mass.